# Which is better, certificate of studies at something (not degree) or years of experience?

Tags: degree, certification

I am currently paying for a master degree, at the same time, I am interested in doing some python extra study, but I dont want to spend money in a python certification, so I am planning to get a course at Udemy or something similar. After that, apply Python in my job. What would it be better for future jobs interviews, years of experience or a diploma?

My question is because I sometimes see people with no high certifications in higher positions that people with certifications.

Comment: Questions about what is most helpful in the generic job market are probably best asked at workplace.SE . Here, people have substantially more experience with the job requirements for academic careers than for careers outside of academia, so unless you're looking for a faculty job, you may get better advice there.

Answer (score 4):

Without a question, experience is more valuable than certification which is almost worthless.  It is not even close.